# Importing scapy to blender

Tags: python, blender, scapy

I'm trying to import the scapy module into blender:

```
from bge import logic
import socket
from scapy.all import *
```

But I face this exception:

[image]

I copied the scapy module folder into:

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules

And this is what it contains:

[image]

Notice all and base_classes is in it.

In addition i tried to add the PYTHONPATH in the environment variables (I'm
not sure this is what I had to do.. I also tried to add

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules\scapy

in the PATH and in PYTHONPATH, they both didn't solve the problem):

[image]

EDIT:

The problem as sambler said is that I used scapy that doesn't support python 3.x as blender uses.
So I download newer scapy version which supports python 3.x from here: https://github.com/phaethon/scapy
and replaced it with the older scapy, now it works but I can't sniff, send or receive packets:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things in the screenshot of the error that giveaway the problem -

- the ^ in the last line is pointing at the `L` in `0xFFL`
- the line above that shows `C:\Python27\scapy\base_classes.py`

From 2.50 onwards blender uses python 3.x and the error causing the exception (L to specify a long int) is a python 2.7 language feature that was removed in 3.0.

A quick search shows a fork of scapy has been made to work with python3

Have a look at [scapy-python3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scapy-python3/)

Comment: Thanks!! That was the problem.. Now scapy works and i can import it Although I can't send or receive packets as I updated in the question.

Comment: Should be a separate question. Have you tried to use scapy outside of blender? As mentioned in [this tutorial](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) you should have admin privileges.

Answer (score 2):

The direct cause of this error is that you don't have `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.75\scripts\modules` in the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable. It's not a specific Blender issue, it's a general Python requirement for loading third-party packages.

You can try to add `PYTHONPATH` as a global per-user environment variable as described in this question: [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i still have a problem.. i edited it in the question.

Comment: See also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/using-3rd-party-python-modules